# How to do delayed postbacks?

Tags: asp.net

I have 5 checkboxes on a hypothetical page, and if any one of them is checked, I want to perform a postback.  However, I would like to delay the postback a bit so that if the user checks a box, it waits a second or so to make sure the user doesn't want to check more boxes before doing the round trip to the server.  So, if you checked all five in rapid succession, you'd be able to check all five before the postback is sent out.

Has anyone done this, seen this done, know how it might be done, or have a good reason not to do it at all?

Answer (score 7):

You didn't say you were using jQuery, but I will assume for the sake of discussion and clarity that it is available.  Something along the lines of this should work for you:

```
var timeout = null;

// Set up code to respond to when the checkbox is checked/unchecked
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    // If this is the second check box in a row, clear previous timeout
    if (timeout != null) 
        clearTimeout(timeout);

    // Set a timeout that will fire in 5 seconds 
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
          // Post back the form
        __doPostBack();
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: Your reply is good. **Query** - There can be the possibility of checking the last or second last `CheckBox` in 5th second may be. Right?. User will definitely feel surprised if `All of the Sudden` my request is sent to server in between.

Comment: @Guest, sure, once the postback is initiated, the user can still click on the checkboxes.  That action will be lost.  Personally I wouldn't use postbacks; I'd post the data via AJAX, probably whenever any of the checkboxes are checked.

Answer (score 7):

Why not put `AutoPostBack="false"` on the checkboxes and the fire the postback via a button?  That way the user has the chance to check everything they want as well as submit the results when they want.

---

Due to your comment about 1 button to postback being counter-intuitive to the user, why not wrap each checkbox in an UpdatePanel?  It may be a bit more markup, but it would do exactly what you want without having to do the "delay the postback" scenario.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox4" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel5" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox5" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: In my opinion, buttons which exist solely to do postbacks are counter-intuitive to the user.  Save buttons people get, but buttons just to do server round-trips seem to confuse some people.

Comment: @Scott - You are given 5 precious upvotes due to your original answer just to keep in mind that it will be useful for future users. So Explicitly mentioning the Edits is good.

Comment: Now you should expect some downvotes for this dangerous `technique`.

Comment: @Guest - There is absolutely nothing **dangerous** about using UpdatePanels. This is how ASP.NET handles ajax out-of-the-box. It's simple. It's effective. It's accomplishes exactly what the OP is trying to do with *very minimal* effort.  Furthermore, the OP is already posting back every single onchange with each of his checkboxes, as they are set to `AutoPostBack="true"`.  UpdatePanels would simply allow them to do so independently of each other and without causing the whole page to be sent back.

Comment: Check http://encosia.com/why-aspnet-ajax-updatepanels-are-dangerous This clearly states your reply is worthless. This reply is not useful for other users.

Comment: @Guest - Again, not true. I am aware of Dave Ward and his post, as I read it 4 years ago. He is using the term **dangerous** liberally. He even admits that UpdatePanels are simple and easy and that when used on a small scale are acceptable solutions.  He's talking about a full blown heavily weighted UpdatePanel solution that would be better fit to be moved to PageMethods.

Comment: His simple example clearly explains that you are committing Blunder here.

Comment: @Guest - Ok Guest, good luck to you and your coding. I'm not going to argue when you fail to even understand what ***scale*** means.

Answer (score 2):

> Has anyone done this, seen this done, know how it might be done, or
>   have a good reason not to do it at all?

I would argue against any delayed action which reloads or modifies the structure of the page. Here's why:

**Reason #1**
People click at vastly different speeds using a wide array of input methods.

**Reason #2**
Behavior should be consistent, not subject to hidden rules that only you know about. Sometimes users are heavily trained and can leverage optimizations, but most of the time they are not.

**Reason #3**
A structural change (especially one performed asynchronously) may undo subsequent actions.

Example:

- User checks a box.
- Page posts back asynchronously after a short delay.
- User unchecks the same box.
- Async postback completes, rechecking the box.

This is a design consideration for any async postback, but the delay makes it even less intuitive.

**Alternative**
If the operation requires that the entire lifecycle be executed when the postback occurs, then I would argue for executing the postback immediately.

If the operation does not require the entire lifecycle of the page to be executed, I suggest executing the logic in the background with an AJAX call of some sort and eliminate the postback completely. You can then use the resulting values to update the browser (if necessary).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem once too. I managed to get it work using a flag stored in a hidden field. Consider this:

```
<%-- SomePage.aspx --%>
<asp:HiddenField ID="checkboxClicked" runat="server" Value="false" />

<asp:CheckBox ID="checkBox1" runat="server" Text="Check 1" AutoPostBack="true" OnClientClick="return onCheckboxClick();" OnClick="OnCheckBoxClick" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="checkBox2" runat="server" Text="Check 2" AutoPostBack="true" OnClientClick="return onCheckboxClick();" OnClick="OnCheckBoxClick" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="checkBox3" runat="server" Text="Check 3" AutoPostBack="true" OnClientClick="return onCheckboxClick();" OnClick="OnCheckBoxClick" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="checkBox4" runat="server" Text="Check 4" AutoPostBack="true" OnClientClick="return onCheckboxClick();" OnClick="OnCheckBoxClick" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="checkBox5" runat="server" Text="Check 5" AutoPostBack="true" OnClientClick="return onCheckboxClick();" OnClick="OnCheckBoxClick" />

<%
    protected void OnCheckBoxClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        // Your code here...

        checkboxClicked.Value = "false";
    }
%>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function onCheckboxClick() {
        var canPostBack = true;

        if ($('#checkboxClicked').val() === 'true') {
            canPostBack = false;
        }
        else {
            $('#checkboxClicked').val('true');
            canPostBack = true;
        }

        return canPostBack;
    }

</script>
```